# stopPropagation or preventDefault in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to remove a mouseover method until I am mouseout but I am using javascript. Is there any similar method whith the ones from jQuery?

This are my events

```
function addEventListeners() {
    document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("mouseover", isClicked);
    document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("mouseleave", collapse);
    document.getElementById("close-button").addEventListener("click", collapse);        
    document.getElementById("box").addEventListener("click", clickthrough);
    document.getElementById("replay").addEventListener("click", replay);
    if(isIphone) document.getElementById("video").addEventListener("click", function(){collapse()});
}

<div id="container">
    <div id="ad" class="collapsed">
        <div id="banner">
            <img class="back" id="back" src="frames/frame_1.jpg"/>
            <img class="top" id="top" src="frames/frame_2.jpg"/>
            <img id="logo1" type="image/svg+xml" src="" />                                              
            <div class="border" id="border"></div>
            <div id="cta"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="expansion">
            <div class="exp_bn" id="exp_bn" >
                <div class="con-pos" id="con-pos" >                                         
                    <div id="videoContainer" class="videoContainer">           
                        <video class="video" id="video" autoplay></video>
                    </div>                                                                        
                </div>                    
            </div>
            <div class="endframe"></div>
            <img id="logo2" type="image/svg+xml" src="" />
            <div id="box"></div>
             <div class="topgrp">
                <div id="close-button" class="icon-cross"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="bottomgrp">
                <div id="replay" class="icon-replay"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "remove a mouseover method until I am mouseout". Mouseover will not trigger while your cursor is out of its content. There is no need to do this manually. What about your title and the latest question - see my answer below.

Comment: When I am mouseover container it will expand. when I mouseleave it will collapse, but when I am expanded I have an x button which if I click it will collapse. But soon as it is collapsed it will expand again

Comment: @MarkusHayner Do you mind adding code in question.

Comment: now you have my events

Comment: @MarkusHayner That is not complete code, also add HTML

Answer (score 0):

`preventDefault` and `stopPropagation` are native JS methods of `event` object.
It is not a part of jQuery.

You can simply use it right in vanilla JS:

```js
document.getElementById("link").onclick = function (e) {
  console.log(e.preventDefault); // function preventDefault() { [native code] }
  console.log(e.stopPropagation); // function stopPropagation() { [native code] }
  
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
};
```

```html
<a href="google.com" id="link">Link</a>
```

Comment: How do I refer on mouseover in this instance? `document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("mouseover", isClicked);
    document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("mouseleave", collapse);
    document.getElementById("close-button").addEventListener("click", function(e){e.stopPropagation(); e.preventDefault(); collapse();});`